# Help correct existing regex to substitute a string value

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and I have been trying to check and substitute a specific value for a string. To illustrate, let me paste the bit of code that I used:-

```
 var1 = re.sub(r'\$this->getSomething()->getSomethingElse()->(.*?)', r'\1', var1)
```

What I am trying to do here is to replace the entire string(var1) with the value contained within (.*?). E.g if the string is in this format "$this->getSomething()->getSomethingElse()->__('Title')" then the new value for var1 should be "__('Title')." At the moment I can't figure out what's wrong with the code and I tried searching all over the place including stackoverflow but not to avail.

Note : This seems to work well though :-

```
value = re.sub(r"\$title", "$this->title", value)
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem or at least direct me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using reluctant matching?

Comment: No any specific reasons. Was trying through many solutions which was posted online. The problem was I didn't escape the parentheses. Thanks for your extremely fast response. Saved me from hours more of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are metacharacters, used for grouping. You also want to match literal parentheses, which means you need to escape some instances. Try:

```
var1 = re.sub(r'\$this->getSomething\(\)->getSomethingElse\(\)->(.*?)', r'\1', var1)
```

Note that this particular statement is equivalent to:

```
var1 = re.sub(r'\$this->getSomething\(\)->getSomethingElse\(\)->', '', var1)
```

and:

```
var1 = var1.replace('$this->getSomething()->getSomethingElse()->', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked well. I realized what I was doing wrong and thanks again for the alternative solutions.